# Can't upload image from app to Hostinger server using PHP

Tags: php, image, upload

Im using a PHP script and a third party PHP API called **PHP_Compat-1.6.0a3** to upload an image from a phone via a android app.

The script and uploading works fine on another server but not working on my paid **HOSTINGER** server

Here is part of the upload script:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/WideImage/lib/WideImage.php';

if($_GET['p']==$ACCESSKEY){
  require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/PHP_Compat-1.6.0a3/Compat/Function/file_get_contents.php');

  $data = php_compat_file_get_contents('php://input');

  if (isset($_GET["thumbnail"]))
   {$thumb=$_GET['thumbnail'];$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mygame/thumbnails/".$thumb;}
  elseif (isset($_GET["filename"]))
   $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mygame/back/".$_GET['filename'];
  else 
   die ("Error: File path missing.");

  if (file_put_contents($filename,$data)) {
    if (filesize($filename) !=0) {

      WideImage::load($filename)->resize($maxWidth, $maxHeight, 'inside', 'down')->saveToFile($filename);
 etc....
}
}
```

**file_put_contents($filename,$data))**  always returns false. So, the file is not uploaded. Can you suggest anything to help please?

Comment: Could you resolve it? Because I have the same problem with hostinguer!

Answer (score 0):

This is because by default hostinger disabled file upload over HTTP you have enabled that manually

Go to Cpanel

1. Advanced section
2. php-configuration

Then go to PHP options and you will find the option of fileUploads.
Enable or check that option
[Look this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FdIF.png)